# UITableView exception when scroll and add cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I ran into this problem that I have searched all over the internet for and still could not find the solution. Please look at the code below:

```
NSLog(@"%i", [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]);  // 4
[self updateCardIDArray];
NSLog(@"%i", [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]);  // 5

int indexOfCreatedCard = [cardIDs indexOfObject:newCardID];        
NSLog(@"%i", indexOfCreatedCard);                                  // 4
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexOfCreatedCard inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:FALSE];

NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexOfCreatedCard inSection:0], nil];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Basically, what I am trying to achieve here is scroll the table to the just created cell and then show an animation of it being added in. When I use this code, I have this error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:1070
```

and this exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.
```

The thing is, if I remove the scrolling and the reload data lines, the program would work normally (without being able to see the add cell animation, of course). Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexOfCreatedCard inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, u are scrolling before cell is inserted, i just posting the sample code that suits ur problem

```
 - (IBAction)scrollPlease:(id)sender 
   {
       aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0); //to move some position below 
       k = k + 1; //hear k is the row numbers in ur case  "indexOfCreatedCard"
       [aTableView beginUpdates]; // first u add the cell to tableview 
       [aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:k-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
       [aTableView endUpdates]; //hear (k - 1) is the last row 
       [aTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:k-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewRowAnimationTop animated:NO]; //then scroll to last cell it will  show the animation of adding the cell 
        aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); // after u set it to zero 

  }
```

hope u get some idea :)

Comment: I did call [tableView reloadData] before scrolling, cells should be added before the tableView scrolled. I tried to insert and then scroll and the app does not crash. Though, the insert animation cannot be seen, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: use [aTableView beginUpdates]; and   [aTableView endUpdates]; for animation to insert and also set  aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0); adjust the value in the bottom space in "contentInset" to see the animation see my updated code u may hav to change the "contentInset" value

Comment: I added the change content inset codes and now it only scroll to right before the new cell, removing these content inset codes and it scroll directly to the added cell but no animation. The thing is, if the new cell is on the screen (content size is less than height), the animation is showed.

Comment: thats wy set the contentInset to some calculated values each time so that u can get whole animation